# Setting text gets rid of children - Jquery

Tags: jquery, html

```
<li class="active">Votes - Most
    <ul id="sortType" title="<%=votesHigh %>">
        <li style="cursor:pointer;" value="<%=votesHigh %>">Votes - Most</li>
        <li style="cursor:pointer;" value="<%=votesLow %>">Votes - Least</li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

Now, I want to set the text of the parent `<li>`, when I select one of the others. This works, but also deletes all the children.

Here's my code:

```
$('li > ul > li').click(function(){
        var val = $(this).attr('value');
        $(this).parent().attr('title', val);
        $(this).parent().parent().text($(this).text());
    });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Encapsulate the "Votes - Most" in a span:

```
<li class="active"><span>Votes - Most</span>
    <ul id="sortType" title="<%=votesHigh %>">
        <li style="cursor:pointer;" value="<%=votesHigh %>">Votes - Most</li>
        <li style="cursor:pointer;" value="<%=votesLow %>">Votes - Least</li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

...and target the span. Something like:

```
$(this).parent().closest("li").find("span:first").text($(this).text());
```

Comment: I've corrected the code, and added an example of the modified HTML.